# java File.listFiles() doesn't return links

Tags: java, file, hyperlink, desktop

I'm trying to use listFiles() method on a file pointing to my desktop folder to read every file on my desktop.

The strange thing is that the method reads some links (.lnk) but can't find some others (ok it can't find the bin icon, but also can't find some others links referencing to some non-windows programs). The same thing happens if I use the command DIR on windows cmd.

How can I resolve this? Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you verified that these are actual files in the `Desktop` directory? They could be "desktop icons" just like the Recycle Bin and others.

Comment: No, I didn't verify that, and I didn't know there was this kind of distinction. Do you know if there is a way to "find" them?

Comment: `dir /a` could do it.

Comment: It doesn't work... However my main problem is to find them in Java

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Please tell the important details -- what does the `dir /a` command show?

Comment: dir /a show exactly what normal dir show, which is "desktop.ini", another file and special folders "." and ".."

Comment: ("desktop.ini" is not shown by normal dir command)

Comment: I ttried, using Files.newDirectoryStream()  I can read desktop.ini and my normal file, but I can't read any other. The method doesn't throw exception

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the files you try and list do not show because they are marked as hidden.

In order to verify that, try this:

```
final Path path = Paths.get("path/to/desktop.ini");
System.out.println(Files.getAttribute(path, "dos:hidden"));
```

Also, try and use this to see whether those files show up:

```
final Path dir = Paths.get("path/to/desktop/folder");
for (final Path entry: Files.newDirectoryStream(dir))
    System.out.println(entry);
```